# React How to fix "Slide to Unlock" Error Message?

Tags: reactjs

I found a snippet with this "Slide to unlock" functionality (https://codepen.io/souporserious/pen/XJQLEb) and try to implement it in my react component (with some changes e.g. class = className). Now I get an error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'min' of undefined, which I cant solve. Did I forget changing parts?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import classes from "./ItemCard.css";


class itemCard extends Component {

  render () {
    var inputRange = document.getElementsByClassName('pullee')[0],
      maxValue = 150, // the higher the smoother when dragging
      speed = 12, // thanks to @pixelass for this
      currValue, rafID;

    // set min/max value
    inputRange.min = 0;
    inputRange.max = maxValue;

    // listen for unlock
    function unlockStartHandler() {
      // clear raf if trying again
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(rafID);

      // set to desired value
      currValue = +this.value;
    }

    function unlockEndHandler() {

      // store current value
      currValue = +this.value;

      // determine if we have reached success or not
      if(currValue >= maxValue) {
          successHandler();
      }
      else {
          rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame(animateHandler);
      }
    }

    // handle range animation
    function animateHandler() {

      // update input range
      inputRange.value = currValue;

      // determine if we need to continue
      if(currValue > -1) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animateHandler);
      }

      // decrement value
      currValue = currValue - speed;
    }

    // handle successful unlock
    function successHandler() {
      alert('unlocked');

      // reset input range
      inputRange.value = 0;
    };

    // bind events
    inputRange.addEventListener('mousedown', unlockStartHandler, false);
    inputRange.addEventListener('mousestart', unlockStartHandler, false);
    inputRange.addEventListener('mouseup', unlockEndHandler, false);
    inputRange.addEventListener('touchend', unlockEndHandler, false);

    return(
      <div className="cardWrapper">
        <div className="cardImage"></div>
        <div className="cardBody">
          <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
          <p>{this.props.description}</p>
          <div className="center-xy">
            <h1>Slide to Unlock</h1>
            <input type="range" value="0" className="pullee" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default itemCard;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all is better to use refs than getElementBy, second thing i would recommend is to extract your functions to the class scope and bind them.

```
<input
    type="range"
    // Using ref
    ref={(el) => { this.inputRange = el; }}
    defaultValue={0}
    min={0}
    max={150}
    className="pullee"
/>
```

```
...
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // binding function in constructor method
    this.unlockStartHandler = this.unlockStartHandler.bind(this);
    this.unlockEndHandler = this.unlockEndHandler.bind(this);
    this.animateHandler = this.animateHandler.bind(this);
    this.successHandler = this.successHandler.bind(this);
    this.maxValue = 150;
    this.speed = 12;
    this.currValue = 0;
    this.rafID = null;
  }
...
```

I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/joseluismurillorios/pen/MNopPb?editors=0010) working for you, is a lot to explain here but hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

your code isn't working because `findElementByClassName` return null and can't find the element with class name `pullee`.

Your code is found in the render function, hence by the time your code is being run the HTML for the component hasn't yet been injected into the dom.

Hence, it is advisable to move all code with reference with your DOM into the `componentDidMount` function or live hook.

More details [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)